# No connection is possible with last firmware builds

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, esp-12f

I am using NodeMCU since a couple of years without problems, usually I build the firmware with these modules:

1. gpio
2. node
3. tmr
4. mqtt
5. wifi
6. file
7. dht
8. net

Yesterday I tried to rebuild the firmware with the same modules and to connect to the device with ESPlorer without success.

I tried also with different modules combination but the problem is the same.

This is what esptool returns:

```
python esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 flash_id
  esptool.py v2.7-dev
  Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
  Connecting....
  Detecting chip type... ESP8266
  Chip is ESP8266EX
  Features: WiFi
  Crystal is 26MHz
  MAC: 68:c6:3a:8b:d8:29
  Uploading stub...
  Running stub...
  Stub running...
  Manufacturer: 20
  Device: 4016
  Detected flash size: 4MB
  Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

If I try to reload the old firmware all works fine.
Working firmware: 2018-05-19
By reading the release notes I found out that I was probably using the version 2.2.0-master_20180402.
Now there is the version 2.2.1-master_20190405.

I am wondering if some major change in the firmware is preventing me to connect again.
Is it possible to build (with the cloud tools) a firmware from a different version?
Does everyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: you mean what changed in the SDK? because we don't know what you changed in your application.

Comment: My application is not involved (I think), I erased the flash, flashed the firmware and then tried to connect with ESPlorer. I have two different behaviour with two different firmware versions (same modules on both).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, on the different versions there are different baud rate settings needed to connect properly.
On the older version I used 9600, now I have to use 11520. After the change everything works fine.

Comment: and this is about esp8266 AT firmware? or what firmware?

Comment: Lua firmware. too many use the NodeMcu not with Lua. so you can'\t expect that everybody knows you use Lua. specially if you mention esp-12F in the same question

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry, I will be more precise next time.